# How to build thirdparty library in submodule with gitlab-ci only when the submodule has changed?

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

My project is using a thirdparty library with git submodule.

Since building the thirdparty library takes too much time, i want to use `rules` in `gitlab-ci` to control the thirdparty building job.

Here is my `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```yaml
stages:
  - extern
  - package

extern:
  stage: extern
  variables:
    GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
  script:
    - cd extern
    - cmake -B build -S . -A x64
    - cmake --build build --config Release --target install
  rules:
    - changes:
        - extern/**/*

package:
  stage: package
  variables:
    GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: none
  script:
    - echo "building..."
```

I want make the extern job only excuted if the submodule head changed in my main repository.

But it didn't meet my expectations. The extern job not running as I expected when I change the submodule head in my main repository.

BTW, I'm using `GitLab CE 14.6.1`

Comment: one reason why it is not working as you expected even after submodule got changed would be - you're changing the submodule content but you're not updating your repository to point to latest changes in submodule. 

try to update your submodules in your repo by - git submodule update --init --recursive --remote

and commit those changes to your repo which points to latest changes in your submodule.

Comment: I already committed the submodule changes in my repo. It seems that my CI was not updating the submodule before checking the rules in my job. My guess is that CI did rules checking first in my job and found no changes in submodule instead of updating submodule first.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming CI_COMMIT_BRANCH holds your feature branch name.
This Shell script gets all the modified files and search for submodule/external file in the modified files. If it is present in modified files then it builds it.

```
changed_files=$(git show --pretty="" --name-only $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH)
SAVEIFS=$IFS   
IFS=$'\n'      
changed_files=(${changed_files})
IFS=$SAVEIFS   
          
for (( i=0; i<${#changed_files[@]}; i++ ))
do
    echo "Changed File - ${changed_files[$i]}"
    if [[ ${changed_files[$i]} != *"extern"* ]]; then
        echo "There are changes in Submodules hence building it"
        cd extern
        cmake -B build -S . -A x64
        cmake --build build --config Release --target install
    fi
done
```